# R: compute an integral with an unknown parameter equal to a certain value (for example: int x = 0.6)

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I try to simulate values out of an unknown integral (to create a climatological forecaster)

my function is: $\int_{x = 0}^{x = 0.25} 4*y^(-1/x) dx$

Normally one inputs the variable `y` and gets a value as output. 
However, I want to input the value this integral is equal to and get the value of `y` as an output.
I have 3 `runif` vectors of length 1 000, 10 000 and 100 000 (with values between 0 and 1), which I use as my input values. 
Say the first value is 0.3 and the second value is 0.78

I want to calculate for which `y`, the integral above is equal to 0.3 (or equal to 0.78 for the second value).

how am I able to do this in R?
I've tried some stuff with the integrate function, but then I need a value for y to make that work

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including your code, inputs and expected output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions or point you to helpful sources. Check out [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve a non-linear equation with an integral inside.

Intuitively, what you need to do is to start with an interval in which the desired y sits on.  Then try different values of y and calculate the integral, narrow the interval by the result.
You can implement that in R using `integrate` and `optimize` as below:

```r
f <- function(x, y) { 
  4*y^(-1/x)
}

intf <- function(y) {
  integrate(f, 0, 0.25, y=y)
}

objective <- function(y, value) {
  abs(intf(y)$value - value)
}

optimize(objective, c(1, 10), value=0.3)
#$minimum
#[1] 1.14745
#
#$objective
#[1] 1.540169e-05

optimize(objective, c(1, 10), value=0.78)
#$minimum
#[1] 1.017891
#
#$objective
#[1] 0.0001655954
```

Here, `f` is the function to be integrated, `intf` calculates the integral for a given y, and `objective` measures the distance between the value of the integral against the desired value.
Since `optimize` function finds the minimum value of a function, it finds y such that the objective is closest to the target value.

Note that non-linear equations with an integral inside are in general tough to solve. This case seems manageable since the function is monotonic and continuous in y.  The solution y should be unique and can be easily found by narrowing down the interval.